# Split list of list (except for values surrounded by quotes "") by comma

Tags: python, list, exception, split

I have this list of lists values and I want to split them by comma, except for value surrounded by quotes ""

> [[Photo Editor & Candy Camera & Grid &
>   ScrapBook,ART_AND_DESIGN,4.1,159,19M,"10,000+",Free,0,Everyone,Art &
>   Design,"January 7, 2018",1.0.0,4.0.3 and up], [Coloring book
>   moana,ART_AND_DESIGN,3.9,967,14M,"500,000+",Free,0,Everyone,Art &
>   Design;Pretend Play,"January 15, 2018",2.0.0,4.0.3 and up], ["U
>   Launcher Lite – FREE Live Cool Themes, Hide
>   Apps",ART_AND_DESIGN,4.7,87510,8.7M,"5,000,000+",Free,0,Everyone,Art &
>   Design,"August 1, 2018",1.2.4,4.0.3 and up], [Sketch - Draw &
>   Paint,ART_AND_DESIGN,4.5,215644,25M,"50,000,000+",Free,0,Teen,Art &
>   Design,"June 8, 2018",Varies with device,4.2 and up]]

Literally I am hopeless and cannot approach it anyhow.

Here is code I tried to but cannot make it work to finish the task:
The code identifies words surrounded by quotes nicely but I have no clue how to say machine to split everything by comma except for values in quotes "".
The values inside quotes should stay together and then I would create Pandas Dataframe.

```
words_in_quotes = []
    for each in google_data:
        start_index = each.find('"')
        endIndex = each.find('"', start_index + 1)
        word_b_quotes = each[start_index:endIndex + 1]
        words_in_quotes.append(word_b_quotes)
```

Comment: if you have it in file then use module `csv` or `pandas.read_csv`

Comment: format the example data of your question in such a way that any one can copy and work on your data.

Comment: it is not correct Python list - if you have it as string then remove `lists_of_list =` and you should have string in JSON format and you could use module `json` to convert all to Python list.

Comment: I am sorry for format errors.... Please try the corrected one

Comment: From where is the data coming from? If from file, you can use for example `csv` module to read and parse it.

Comment: Data are just pure list of lists as shown.

Comment: is that a string? '[[Photo Editor & Candy Camera & Grid &...,4.2 and up]]' cuz is not a list